# Build only when test cases are passed

Tags: unit-testing, npm, gulp, karma-runner, webpack

```
{
...,
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run test & gulp & webpack",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
...
}
```

I want to abort build process if all test cases are not passed.

Is there any solution for this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `&&` instead of `&`:

```
npm run test && gulp && webpack
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with this:

```
{
...,
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "npm test",
    "build": "gulp && webpack",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
...
}
```

npm scripts prefixed with *pre* will be executed before than your script without prefix, and if it return with other code than **0**, it will abort the process. Furthermore there is anohter *post* prefix, that will be executed after your script. You can read more about this *npm* feature [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).